# Peer-to-Peer 1080p live streaming using WebRTC/Alternative?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, p2p, webrtc, getusermedia

I've been experimenting with WebRTC and its ability to stream video/audio using p2p, however I've found that it's not able to stream any resolutions > 720p. Using `getUserMedia()` I'm able to capture the local webcam in 1080p, but it seems to fail at encoding/decoding in 1080p (I'm not sure which it is) and the client-side displays the video in 1280x720.

There are a few bug reports regarding this issue: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259440) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1750&q=1080p&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).

Is there a way I can capture the webcam using `getUserMedia()`, encode the video myself in 1080p and still use WebRTC for its peer-to-peer capabilities?

Basically I'm trying to achieve the same sort of thing shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zInFAJ-xCWM). That is, live streaming a video and sharing it with other viewers so there's significantly less server/broadcaster bandwidth used. WebRTC seemed the obvious choice for this.

Are there any alternative solutions, besides waiting for the WebRTC bug to be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI for other readers: These bugs are now fixed and 1080p support works in Chrome. (Currently M40)

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved on the tickets you posted:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1750

Which points to this [url for verification](https://apprtc.appspot.com/?debug=loopback&video=minWidth=1920,minHeight=1080).